# tools / utilities used to make web based video-editor. ( like animoto or stupeflix )

Tags: c++, c, video-processing

I am a great fan of the video editing sites animoto (and stupiflex), i enjoy computer graphics  and also have that as my major subject at university.

My question is, I have trying to guess what would one need inorder to build such an application.

Do any such open-source / free tools do exist that can give the kind of quality offered by these professionally built products ?

--I've stumbled upon opensource multimedia framework GStreamer, but i'm have no idea if it can deliver here.

--And have been using OpenCV for academic purposes, would that be a better library ?

UPDATED: 
1, my problems are only with the serverside video processing, 
2, since this is more of a hobby/adacemic project i'm looking for free & open sources linux based tools/sdks for my task.

Please share your ideas,
thanks.

Comment: @gf he has only asked 8 questions. And there is no requirement that he accepts ANY, so he is doing OK.

Comment: @Neil - i didn't mean to imply any requirement, just got used to dropping a diplomatic reminder sometimes... And i confess, i didn't see that it were only 8.

Comment: @phoenix24: i forgot, should it be cross-platform or for a specific platform?

Comment: @gf - I'm looking for a linux based solution, moreover this is more of a adacemic / hobby project. so the cheaper the alternatives the better.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out http://www.openmovieeditor.org/?